# How to get data from a checkbox selection?

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using AG-grid with checkbox selection and multiple rows selections.
I don't understand how to get data from a checkbox selection as the `rowClicked` event doesn't trigger on checkbox selection.

[image]

This is my table. When clicking on checkbox header, it selects every row. I can also select each individual row and multi select them. I want to perform an action on selected rows but have some hard time doing so.

First, I cannot manage to grab the event that is triggered when using the checkbox selection. I currently only use `rowClicked` that is triggered when I click on a row. On rowClicked, I push the current row to an array. But I can't manage to properly remove the row from the array when deselecting the row.

1. How can I manage to get checkbox clicked event?
2. Is there a built-in system that lets me perform an action on the rows I clicked/checked? If not, what is the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to me like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/226277)

> On rowClicked, I push the current row to an array. But I can't manage to properly remove the row from the array when deselecting the row.

Why do you need to manage the selection yourself? If you are using `clientSide` row model (looking at your screenshot it seems) *or even `serverSide` or `infinite`*, you can get the selected rows by using `gridApi`.

```
gridApi.getSelectedRows()
```

There is another event `SelectionChangedEvent` which is raised whenever the records selection is changed. As in your situation, records selection is updated whenever you click on any checkbox or any row, this can be useful to you.

If this doesn't answer your original question, leave comment, will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In here you have all the events that the grid fires

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/

You just need to add listeners to the appropriate events.

Hope this helps